# can a container have a higher resource demain than an individual node

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've tried looking for the answer but i cant seem to word it in the right way to find what im after.

Could I have a container that needs 6gb of ram for example but I only have 3 nodes wih 4gb each? Would it get split across multiple nodes? I suppose it depends on what the container is running.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Containers cant use more resources then nodes, where they are scheduled. If your container need more resources than any of cluster's node have - it simply wont be scheduled.

Below part taken from partially-related article [Specify a memory request that is too big for your Nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#specify-a-memory-request-that-is-too-big-for-your-nodes) , but it contains important info:

> Pod scheduling is based on requests. A Pod is scheduled to run on a
> Node only if the Node has enough available memory to satisfy the Pod's
> memory request.

also

> The scheduler ensures that there are enough resources for all pods on
> a node based on the pod requests. It verifies that the sum of requests
> of containers on the node is no greater than the node capacity. It
> includes all containers started by the node, but not containers or
> processes started outside the knowledge of the cluster.

If you would try to schedule pod that requires more resources(i mean `resources.request`) that any of your nodes  have - pod will remain in Pending state with `FailedScheduling` error.